# ¿Como hago para que un jTable sea publica?

Tags: java, jframe, jtable

Necesito usar un valor de una jTable (la tabla esta ubicada en otro jFrame, dentro del mismo Package) en otro jFrame de Java, para esto estoy usando un getSelectedRow(), hasta el momento todo bien, pero el código me arroja un error, diciendo que: "jTable has private access in ...."
Al parecer lo único que necesito es hacer que la tabla pase de ser private a public, pero no sé como hacerlo...
Por cierto, estoy usando netbeans ;)

Comment: Hey Ariel bienvenido!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu pregunta debes modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad requerida en el sitio, esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que todo hay que revisar como estás creando el jTable, para poder compartir información entre formularios debes invocar a una instancia del formulario activa y pasar una copia al otro formulario y el jTable debería ser una variable de clase pública ( o privada con su respectivo getter() and setter() preferiblemente) y ahí si podrías usarla

```html
public class FormA{

public jTable tabla;

//constructor vacio
public formA(){
}

}

public class FormB{

public FormB(){
FormA formulario = new FormA();
//acá ahora puedes usar formulario.tabla y obtener toda la data que //necesites
}

}
```